# Django redirection without changing the browser's URL

Tags: python, django, .htaccess

I've got a Django app running on localhost:80, and another app running on localhost:41984. Now, in the app, I'm trying to hook things up so that hitting localhost/view/41984 redirects to localhost:41984, without changing the URL in the browser: effectively, URL masking of sorts.

Could someone give me some pointers on achieving this? Django's HttpResponseRedirect does the redirection, but the URL changes too, which isn't what I want. I read somewhere that people do this with .htaccess, but I'm not planning on using Apache.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best option should be, to run both app in the same server. Just add one to the INSTALLED_APPS list.

Then, you can do:

```
return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
```

The view name is the one you define in the urls.py file:

```
url(r'^enter/$', 'yourApp.views.viewName', name='some-view-name'),
```

For more info  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

If you need to run booth app in differents servers... I would say that you need a REAL web server, apache, ngix... what you want, but no ./manage.py runserver

Comment: My bad - I should have mentioned this. Right now, the other app, to which I want to be redirected to, isn't a Django app. Plain Tornado, that one.

Comment: However, having said that - Django's redirect() is inherently a temporary redirect, isn't it? I read that in the link you posted. After reading through the RFC, I gather that a simple redirect function could be enough. I'll try it and let you know how it goes!